# Randomizing an Array of restaurants

Tags: c#, arrays, random

For my Intro to computer science class I have to make an application to select restaurants with various capabilities, I can't figure out how to randomize the array though.
Below is my code.

```
string[] myRestaurants = new string[9];

myRestaurants[0] = "Wendy's";
myRestaurants[1] = "Arby's";
myRestaurants[2] = "Olive Garden";
myRestaurants[3] = "The Pie";
myRestaurants[4] = "The Cheesecake Factory";
myRestaurants[5] = "Beto's";
myRestaurants[6] = "Dillinger's Saloon";
myRestaurants[7] = "Dayz Alpher";
myRestaurants[8] = "Firehouse subs";

var nextArray = myRestaurants.ToList();
Random rng = new Random();  
int n = nextArray.Count;
while (n > 1)
{
    n--;
    int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
    T value = nextArray[k];
    nextArray[k] = nextArray[n];
    nextArray[n] = value;
    //bang
}
```

Comment: You can't just declare a generic variable in a method body, that's not how it works. Can you remove everything that isn't relevant?

Answer (score 5):

You can randomize it with LINQ and the `OrderBy` method.. coupled with your `Random` class:

```
myRestaurants = myRestaurants
                    .OrderBy(x => myRandom.Next(myRestaurants.Length))
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: +1.  This will work pretty well, but the obsessive in me wants to point out the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is an efficient way to produce a 'fairly' shuffled list.

Comment: Why would you put effort in implementing an algorithm when you can do the same with one line of code. I highly doubt restaurant order is crucial and needs top notch randomizing.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Given it's a three-line in-place algorithm which runs about as efficiently as possible and provides a better distribution, why not?  In this case the LINQ method is probably fine, but it's worth noting the proper way to do it when distribution or performance matters.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin If you're interested, I added an answer with the Fisher-Yates mechanism. :)

Answer (score 1):

The example below pics items randomly.

```
Random rand=new Random();
string[] RandomArray = myRestaurants.OrderBy(r => rand.Next()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic implementation using the Fisher-Yates mechanism:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var r = rnd.Next(i + 1);
            T value = list[r];
            list[r] = list[i];
            list[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myRestaurants.Shuffle();
```

Example output:

- The Pie
- Dillinger's Saloon
- Beto's
- Olive Garden
- The Cheesecake Factory
- Dayz Alpher
- Firehouse subs
- Arby's
- Wendy's